# PHP Error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'rating'

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed stamped.io plugin for customer reviews on my wordpress website and on front end I'm receiving an error 'Warning: Illegal string offset 'rating' in /plugins/stampedio-product-reviews/view/cls_stamped_io_public.php on line 29'

And I dig into the file, here's the code on line 29 (actually the line with the `if` statement):

```
if ($agrr_review["rating"] != "0" && $agrr_review["rating"] != 0){

$markup['aggregateRating'] = array('@type' => 'AggregateRating',

'ratingValue' => $agrr_review["rating"],

'ratingCount' => $agrr_review["count"],

'reviewCount' => $agrr_review["count"],

'worstRating' => 1,

'bestRating' => 5,

);
```

It's just a warning error so I just want to shut it up. Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `$agrr_review["rating"] != "0" && $agrr_review["rating"] != 0` is redundant since `"0" == 0` is true. Also true is: `"" == 0` but not `"" == "0"`.

However, since in that case a calculation with the empty string would not make sense, you can simplify your condition to:

```
if (!empty($agrr_review['rating']))
```

`empty` is `true` for any expression that evaluates to `false`, including the empty string `""`, the value `0`, the string `"0"` and unset variables. It does not throw a warning.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code worked worked too. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the $agrr_review is something else of an array 
example

```
 $agrr_review="";
    if ( $agrr_review["rating"] != "0" && $agrr_review["rating"] != 0){
    }
```

then you'll get

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'rating'

so to 'shut it up' you could do following:

```
$agrr_review="";
if (is_array($agrr_review) && $agrr_review["rating"] != "0" && $agrr_review["rating"] != 0){
}
```

But you still can get an error if 'rating' is not in your array:

> Undefined index: rating

so you need another condition:

```
if (is_array($agrr_review) && isset($agrr_review["rating"])&& $agrr_review["rating"] != "0" && $agrr_review["rating"] != 0){
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first code worked perfectly without giving me an error 'Undefined index: rating'.